# Error on posting data to server only in safari

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, post, safari

Code works perfect in Chrome, IE9, FF except in Safari on win7.
Have not tried Safari on an ipad yet.
The data being sent to the server looks fine in the safari console.

This is the error that is returned to the client when it fails.

```
    {
        "ExceptionDetail":{
            "HelpLink":null,
            "InnerException":{
                "HelpLink":null,
                "InnerException":null,
                "Message":"The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).",
                "StackTrace":"   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)",
                "Type":"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException"
            },
            "Message":"Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'SaveILOData'. The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).",
            "StackTrace":"   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)",
            "Type":"System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException"
        },
        "ExceptionType":"System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException",
        "Message":"Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'SaveILOData'. The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).",
        "StackTrace":"   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)"
    }
```

Here is the JavaScript the error function gets called only on Safari

```
    function SaveILO(exitEditor) {
        var templateID = $("#<%=DropDownListAssetTypes.ClientID%>").val();
        var dataValue = jseditor.getValue();
        var json = JSON.stringify({ "iloID": "<%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>", "iloData": dataValue, "iloTypeID": templateID });
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: false,
            url: '../services/jsonservices.svc/SaveILOData',
            data: json,
            success: function (msg) {
                SetStatusMessage('');
                if (exitEditor)
                    top.document.location.href = '../';
                //parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
            },
            error: function (msg, textStatus) {
                alert("There was an error saving the ILO." );
            },
        });
    }
```

Here is the service

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public string SaveILOData(string iloID, string iloData, int iloTypeID)
    {
        using (ILOManagerRepository dc = new ILOManagerRepository())
        {
            dc.AddEditILOData(iloID, iloData,iloTypeID);
        }
        return "success";

    }
```

Here is the saving function ILOManagerRepository

```
    public string AddEditILOData(string identifier, string iloData, int iloTypeID)
    {
        ILOData d = GetILODataByIdentifier(identifier);
        ILO i = GetILOByIdentifier(identifier);

        if (d == null)
        {
            d = new ILOData();
            db.ILODatas.Add(d);
        }

        i.TypeID = iloTypeID;
        d.ILOID = i.ILOID;
        d.Data = iloData;
        d.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return d.ILODataID.ToString();
    }
```

As you can see nothing special is going on here and it does work for all browsers but Safari.

[UPDATE]
Ok here is an interesting update.
When I call the SaveILO function the response comes back with the error posted above.
But when I call the function right after that error response the second time around it will succeed.

Comment: If you are familiar at all with this error please help. .net is not my first language so any help at all is welcomed.

Comment: Try to compare actual request from Safari and other working browsers. For that purpose you can use Fiddler. This should give you a clue what is invoking error on Safari.

Comment: Can you show the Request Header? You can see it on the safari console.
Show from safari and one from chrome for indicate.